# Partial Differential Equations to Describe Electric Current

Tags: motion

I am a newbie in PDE. I know that Navier-Stokes equations are used to describe the motion of viscous fluid substances, what are the equivalent partial differential equations that are used to describe the motion of electric current in wires?

Comment: Two models come to mind: One is modeling electrons as a large number of free electrons (see [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model)). The other is the famous set of Maxwell's Equations. With that said, it seems like PDEs are a solution looking for a problem. First find an engineering problem you wish to solve, and *then* decide whether PDEs are the best technique to use.

Comment: Google  "telegrapher's equations".

Comment: @ThePhoton, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they're "equivalent" to the Navier-Stokes equations, because they describe an essentially 1-dimensional system while Navier-Stokes describe a 3-dimensional system, but we typically describe the propagation of current and voltage signals on a transmission line (a pair of wires) using the  [Telegrapher's Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations).

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = -L\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = -C\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$$

where \$x\$ is position along the transmission line, \$L\$ is the inductance per unit length of line, and \$C\$ is the capacitance per unit length of line.

I won't say much more because it's probably your homework question to research this problem further, but the main thing we do with these equations is derive the 1-dimensional wave equation from them, showing that signals propagate along transmission lines as waves.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Photon. So, does this equation represents the same transmission line going to house and to electrical substations alike?

Comment: @Abraheem, it does, but at power transmission frequencies (50-60 Hz) wave effects will only be important over very long distances (~500 km or so). At data signalling frequencies (10's of kHz and up as in telegraph, telephone and modern data transmission) they will be important at much shorter lengths of line.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, after 500 km, I have to study some effects but before 500 km, the equation is the same for the house and for electrical substations? Sorry, but I am not EE, so I am trying to make sure I understand your answer.

Comment: It means if the length of the power line is less than 500 km, you don't need to use these equations because you can just assume the voltages and currents are the same at all locations on the line.

Comment: Thank you very much.